# Use iPod Classic Without iTunes

Tags: ipod

I use a program called iShuffle with my iPod shuffle. All I do is copy music files in Windows Explorer to the Shuffle's Music folder, then run the little app and it magically works without iTunes.

http://agoraphobeus.free.fr/iShuffle/index.html

Is there an equivalent for the iPod Classic line, and older generations of that line?

Comment: Can you add some details to make it easier to answer the question: Are you looking for a Windows specific solution or is OS X also acceptable? Do you only want to copy music or other stuff (e.g. photos) as well?

Comment: Windows, primarily. But Cross platform would be great. Just music. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You could try using Rockbox, however you might want to check whether or not your iPod is supported. Rockbox is an alternative firmware for your iPod classic that allows you to copy music files just like a normal MP3 player.

http://www.rockbox.org/wiki/IpodFAQ

It even plays Doom!

Comment: Can you get Rockbox to load the original apple shell? Or will you be stuck with Rockbox's own GUI?

Comment: There are probably skins that look like the Apple firmware. You can tell Rockbox to boot into the Apple firmware, but music you've copied via Rockbox won't appear.

Comment: Oh, ok. Then I don't think Rockbox is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Foobar2000](http://www.foobar2000.org/) which is an amazing music player and manager for Windows.  There are dozens (if not hundreds) of [add-ons](http://www.foobar2000.org/components), one of which adding iPod control.  I personally use this software and it makes managing songs on the iPod very easy.

The iPod components has many features and supports album artwork.  It also gives you the option of converting unsupported audio formats (such as FLAC) when you add those to the iPod.

Comment: Ahh I see your approach. We can use other software that's been tailored to support the iPod instead of iTunes to get around iTunes... Interesting.